# I'm trying to append an option value to a form action

Tags: html, forms, get

I'm trying to append an option value to a form action, using method get. Submit sends the form request but isn't attaching the select option to the action?

So when the form is submitted it should use >

**https://url.here.com?domain= users search here + selected option?**

Thanks in advance.

```
    <form action="https://url.here.com?domain=" method="get">
                <div class="just-arrived-search">
                    www.<input type="search" name="domain" placeholder="Search" />
                    <select>
                        <option value="">All</option>
                        <option value=".bike">.bike</option>
                        <option value=".clothing">.clothing</option>
                        <option value=".guru">.guru</option>
                        <option value=".holding">.holdings</option>
                        <option value=".plumbing">.plumbing</option>
                        <option value=".singles">.singles</option>
                        <option value=".venture">.ventures</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn-new" type="submit">Register Domain</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Cool, so what's your question? What's not working?

Comment: The output from the form isn't appending the select option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since you edited your initial post to more clearly explain what you are attempting to achieve, here is a simple solution to your issue.

Use JavaScript to append the selected value to the domain before it submits. Change the button to have an `onclick` attribute as oppose to making it submit the form.

Add this JavaScript to your head section (or wherever you want, but convention is typically the HEAD section or bottom of the body):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        var ext = document.getElementById('ext');
        var selected_opt = ext.options[ext.selectedIndex].value;

        // Add own code to handle "All" here

        var domain = document.getElementById('domain');
        // Append selected option
        domain.value = domain.value + selected_opt;

        // Submit form
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

And this is the updated HTML code to go along with it:

```
<form action="https://url.here.com" method="get" id="myForm">
    <div class="just-arrived-search">
        www.<input type="search" id="domain" name="domain" placeholder="Search" />
        <select id="ext">
            <option>All</option>
            <option>.bike</option>
            <option>.clothing</option>
            <option>.guru</option>
            <option>.holdings</option>
            <option>.plumbing</option>
            <option>.singles</option>
            <option>.ventures</option>
        </select>
        <button class="btn-new" onclick="submitForm();">Register Domain</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, unfortunately the key ?ext= needs to be removed from what is output, is this possible?

Comment: Well, it is but it's a bit of a hack. You would have to rewrite the URL on the other side.

Consider using POST instead of GET. POST's data is not passed through the URL like GET parameters are.

Comment: POST completely ignores the dropdown selection??

Comment: POST sends the information in the request message's body as oppose to the URL itself. Therefore, it seems "invisible" to the user. You'll need to process the data on the other side with something, like PHP. Read this article for more information on POST: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)

Comment: I updated my answer since you provided more information about what you want in your original post.